# summing a square array

Tags: sum, fortran

Hi I am trying to sum a 2-dimensional square array.  Assume the array `F(i,j)` is well defined for all points `i,j`.  I can sum the whole array by just `sum(F)`, but I want to sum the array by starting from a small square, and then up to the full size array, which will require a `DO` loop.   If I was to write out the logic tediously, I want to sum the array `F(i,j)` as follows:

```
DO i = -1,1
DO j = -1,1

     value1 = sum(F)

END DO
END DO

DO i = -2,2
DO j = -2,2

     value2 = sum(F)

END DO
END DO

DO i = -3,3
DO j = -3,3

     value3 = sum(F)

END DO
END DO
```

and proceed up to `i=-30,30, j=-30,30`.  I tried to implement this in one `DO` loop by

```
DO i = -30,30
DO j = -30,30

     value4 = sum(F(i:i+1,j:j+1))

END DO
END DO
```

but this gives me incorrect results.  How can I fix this so I can implement this in all in a single do loop? Thanks.

Comment: Please report the incorrect results and show a [mcve].

Comment: @VladimirF Please see solution below.

Comment: I have expected this solution from the beginning but you have still not explained what I requested, mainly the incorrect results. They really should be in your question. It is very incomplete and the answer does not and cannot explain any explanation for your wrong results. Or just do not mention them at all. You should not require any guessing from your answerers. Hence my new downvote.

Answer (score 3):

If I am deciphering what you are trying to do, you have a 2-D array with custom extents from -30 to 30 in both dimensions? Then you want to start with a 3x3 matrix in the center of this, get a sum. Then enlarge it to a 5x5 and get a sum. Keep going until you get the sum of the whole matrix.

You will have 30 sums then. Yes you can do this in a single do loop. Putting the answers in a 1-D array Sums(30) would look like this:

```
do i = 1, 30
   Sums(i) = Sum(F(-i:i,-i:i))
end do
```

The index notation in F carves out growing square matrices to feed into the Sum function.